# Java: Pictures don't load when exported

Tags: java, image, jar, export

So, as the title pretty much says, my application works just like it should in eclipse, but when I export my application, the gui just shows a blank screen. I know it has to do with the pictures since when I use the program (it's tic tac toe), it still works like it should. Continuing, I understand that the problem has to do with how I load in the images. Here's an example:
    background.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src\board.png"));
Is the file path insufficiently defined for it to be found when exported? There's no errors, which is good, but it doesn't help either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put the images in the jar and use a getResource method to read them.  Do a search for full code examples.

Comment: Thanks! I know it's probably a silly question to ask, but I'm just learning guis, so this really helped out.

Comment: Two things, 1- "src" is not likely to be available at runtime, so you should never use it ask part of your path. 2- ImageIcon(String) expects a File reference, but it appears as you are trying to embed the image within the application. If you are using eclipse, these should be stored in the "resources" folder and (regardless of the IDE), accessed using something like getClass().getResource(String)